# Passing arguments to the constructor of an @Injectable in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

Suppose we have an `@Injectable` class like this:

```
interface IServiceConfig {
    boo: string;
    foo: string;
}

@Injectable()
class Service {
    boo: string = "boo";
    foo: string = "foo";

    constructor(IServiceConfig isc) {
       Object.assign(this, isc);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to pass an `IServiceConfig` instance to the constructor of `Service` while still allowing Angular to create and inject the `Service` instance?

Is there a different way to configure Services prior to Angular creating instances of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested, but you should be able to do like this:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';

interface IServiceConfig {
    boo: string;
    foo: string;
}

@Injectable()
class Service {
    boo: string = "boo";
    foo: string = "foo";

    constructor(@Inject('isc') @Optional() public isc?: IServiceConfig ) {
       Object.assign(this, isc);
    }
}
```

An in your providers (e.g. in app.module):

```
providers: [
    {provide: 'isc', useValue: {boo: 'hoo', foo: 'bar'},
...
```

Comment: Neat and elegant!  Hope it works!  Either way I like it so much I'm going to vote it up and accept!